# Solve $dX_t=(a+bW_t)dt+cdW_t.$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

> Question: If $a,b,c$ are constants and $W_t$ is a Brownian motion, solve the following SDE
>   $$dX_t=(a+bW_t)dt+cdW_t.$$

First of all, this is not a linear SDE due to presence of $W_t$.

I attempted any form of integration factor but to no avail.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: At the moment this is an ODE on every point of the probability space if the Brownian motion is chosen to have continuous paths. Was the second $dt$ intended to be a $dW_t$? As $X$ does not occur on the right side, this is an inhomogeneous linear ODE or SDE, even simpler as it is just a quadrature problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right on the second term. Edited.

Comment: So your solution is $X_t=X_0+at+cW_t+b\int_0^tW_s\,ds$. There is noting more that can be said.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed as mentioned in the comments the process
$$X_{t}=aB_{t}+b\int^t B_{s}ds=\int_{0}^{t}a+b(t-s)dB_{s}.$$

is as far as one can go. If you are interested in its law (Gaussian) see here  [Expectation of time integral of Wiener process](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42104/expectation-of-time-integral-of-wiener-process) and [Integral of Brownian motion w.r.t. time](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/29504/integral-of-brownian-motion-w-r-t-time).